# What is the "POSIX-defined format" for command-line error messages? Which standard?

Tags: c, ruby, standards, posix, getopt

On ruby-doc.org [page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html#method-c-new)
I found the following about command-line options/arguments parsing (getopt library):

> Return the appropriate error message in POSIX-defined format. If no error has occurred, returns nil.

What is POSIX-defined format for command-line error messages? Which POSIX standard is it?

**EDIT:**

I must clarify that I was interested in standard/recommended error messages when 
parsing command line arguments/options.

In the links below (answers) I found only mentioning this error format for getopt:

```
"%s: illegal option -- %c\n", <program name>, <option character>

"%s: option requires an argument -- %c\n", <program name>, <option character>
```

Is it all to it?

Answer (score 3):

IEEE Std 1003.1 it is. See [`errno.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html), [Error Numbers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html). Also known as POSIX.1-2008, and earlier revisions (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) for more details on sections, years etc).

Note that systems are likely to have extended set of error numbers and messages associated with them. For example, Linux supports error numbers defined by C99. There could be implementation-specific errors as well. Here is Linux's [`errno.h`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is about the `getopt()` function, presumably, you are looking for the POSIX specification of the [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function.  The specification for that defers to the [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) utility for the error messages it can produce.  The rationale section of the `getopts` utility describes the format of some error messages in some existing implementations, but does not mandate them.

You should also look at the [Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) specification for the rules that a POSIX utility normally conforms to.  (There are deviations from the conventions, normally because of long-established historical precedent.  There is, typically, a variation defined which matches the POSIX conventions.)