# How to handle missing commandline arguments/options to commandline arguments?

Tags: bash

I've written a bash script allows several long as well as short options. This works pretty well but I'm unsure how to handle

- missing long options
- missing short options
- missing arguments to options
- whatever I didn't think of

The only advice I found so far is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10866443/1178669) but the answers don't really go much into detail.

Is there some document which describes how to handle this? Or is this left to the implementer?

Comment: How did you implement the option parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Use [getopt(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) in bash. [Here](http://linuxwell.com/tag/getopt1/) is nice tutorial about it.

if you want to stick to pure bash use [getopts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopts). Its bash built in. Here is [tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) (thanks  gniourf_gniourf in comments bellow)

Comment: In bash, don't use the external `getopt`, use the builtin `getopts` instead. See [this nice link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Comment: :P I thought getopt is be buil-in one. Whatever, I have added that information.